# How do I use 'metadata=1' with an Edge in the Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

In the Graph API Explorer:

`me?metadata=1` gives:

```
"metadata": {
    "fields": [
      {
        "name": "about",
        "description": "*Returns no data as of April 4, 2018.*",
        "type": "string"
      },
// etc
```

so that I can see all fields available on `me`.

I want to view the fields for `me/likes` but if I enter `me/likes?metadata=1` it just shows me the actual data - the same that `me/like` returned.

How can I view the metadata?

Comment: This appears to only be available for nodes, not edges. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/overview?locale=en_US#node-metadata

Comment: Thanks, that would make sense give I can only get it to work on nodes.